Conver ISO 8601 String to date
I was wondering how I would be take this '2023-06-14T17:48:52.012Z' ISO8601 string and convert it all the way to a date?
I have tried this
SELECT '2023-06-14T17:48:52.012Z'::timestampz::date

but this didn't work, was wondering if there were other methods to do that

You mistyped timestamptz omitting a "t". SELECT '2023-06-14T17:48:52.012Z'::timestamptz::date works just fine.

Not understanding the issue: SELECT '2023-06-14T17:48:52.012Z'::date; 2023-06-14.  You will need to be more specific about what you got vs what you expected. Add as text update to question text.

You may use the TO_TIMESTAMP() function with a custom formatting mask:
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-06-14T17:48:52.012Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.MSZ')::date
-- 2023-06-14

